# Direction vector for gravity

Tags: newtonian-gravity, vectors

I have co-ordinate axes on the earth's surface (and I've been told these are the axes I have to use). Ignoring z, I have x and y axes.

The question asks me to calculate the acceleration due to gravity as a vector, using Newton's law of gravitation.

I know g = -GM**r**/a^3, where **r** is the position vector of some object experiencing the force of gravity and a is the object's distance. But the equation for g assumes an origin at the earth's centre, and my x and y aren't defined relative to those axes, so I have to modify them. 
My problem is that I can't work out the position vector. I know in the y direction it'll be earth's radius + y, but in x it's more complicated.

Essentially, what is the vector that points from my x axis on earth's surface to the centre of the earth??

Comment: $\hat{r}$ is a vague definition that doesn't point in any specific direction (meaning if the object moves, the direction of $\hat{r}$ changes), and can usually be defined in terms of a chosen cartesian coordinate system with components $x$, $y$, and $z$.  I assume here your $y$ axis is vertical from the earth's surface.  If that is the case, your $y$ axis is parallel to $\hat{r}$ and $x$ is perpendicular to that.

Comment: The two values are latitude and longitude that give you angular measurements from the center of the sphere represented by the earth. You have to place the origin of a cartesian coordinate system at the center and calculate the projection of a redius, going to a particular latitude and longitude, onto the x,y and z axes using sines and cosines. The projctions onto the axes will give you the components of the vectors represented by the gravitational force at a point on the surface.